# Return an array of all indexes of a certain character?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do should be very simple and I'm not sure why my code isn't working. I'm creating a function that is supposed to return an array of all the indexes of a specified character.

```
    var str = "audiueaaudliusa";
    str = str.split("");
    var emptyArr = [];

    function abCheck(str) {
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
          if(str[i] === "a") {
            emptyArr.push(str.indexOf(str[i]));
          }
        }
        return emptyArr;
    }
```

In the above example, it returns an array of [0, 0, 0, 0]. I would expect the code to return an array of [0, 6, 7, 14].

Please offer a solution and if possible explain what's going wrong here.

Comment: don't make `i` global either.  `for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line `emptyArr.push(str.indexOf(str[i]));` and is a problem because `String.indexOf()` returns the index of the *first* matched instance of the character.

As noted in the comments, the correction for this problem is to simply use:

```
emptyArr.push(i);
```

Which pushes the current index, represented by `i`, into the array:

```js
var str = "audiueaaudliusa";
var emptyArr = [];

function abCheck(str) {

  // in the for loop I've made a couple of small changes:
  // - made 'i' and 'len' local variables,
  // - used 'len' in order that the 'str.length' wouldn't
  //   need to be reevaluated on each iteration (it's a tiny,
  //   tiny optimisation though):
  for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (str[i] === "a") {
      emptyArr.push(i);
    }
  }
  return emptyArr;
}

console.log(abCheck(str)); // [0, 6, 7, 14]
```

References:

- [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).