# Python - Array of Indexes of all appearances of a certain element in an array

Tags: python, list

This question is very similar to this question, [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802449/return-an-array-of-all-indexes-of-a-certain-character), except for the fact that I need an answer for Python.

I'll explain the question anyway. If I have an array of characters, for example `["a", "b", "a", "c"]`, then it needs to return an array that includes the indexes of all the appearances of a certain character.

This means that if I input `['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a']`, and I need to find all appearances of `'a'`, then it would output `[0, 2, 5]`.

I also need the program to be pretty fast, as I need to mass generate my final product, so the whole program needs to be quick. I will probably be running this piece of code millions of times in my code so the quicker it is the better, but I am accepting anything right now.

Right now my code does not work since it simply output `[0, 0, 0]` (I am running through a for loop so it isn't fast either)

Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Use Numpy if you need speed fir these functions. They are built in.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Why is it a list of characters instead of a string? String might allow faster solutions.

Comment: @ethan: would would this be? I am already using a lot of numpy in my code, so what would this build-in function be?

Comment: @Bob Robert. If you create a masked array you can use np.where(myMaskedArray==‘a’) and it will return an array of indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the np.where function.

```
>>> l=np.array(['a','b','a','c','c','a'])
>>> np.where(l=='a')
(array([0, 2, 5]),)
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple option, not optimised for speed:

```py
list_of_characters = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a']
character = 'a'
index_list = [i for i,v in enumerate(list_of_characters) if v == character]
```

Edit: If you're doing this calculation a lot and the list doesn't change between each run, you should pre-compute the solutions and store them in an easily accessible format.

Comment: Never use `list` as a variable name, as it clobbers the builtin `list` command, otherwise good solution to find the index locations of a single character.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to default the index locations of each character to a list, then just enumerate over your list and append the index locations.  This allows you to later index the location of *any* character in the list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a']

dd = defaultdict(list)
for n, c in enumerate(my_list):
    dd[c].append(n)

>>> dd['a']
[0, 2, 5]

>>> dict(dd)
{'a': [0, 2, 5], 'b': [1], 'c': [3, 4]}
```

Comment: This would be nice, except for the fact that it would use unnecessary memory and time (I know, very slight, but every millisecond here makes a difference).